# Rails Nested Eager Loading?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry, eager-loading

Lets say we have a nested set up where

```
class Foo
  belongs_to :object
  has_many :bar
end

class Bar
  belongs_to :foo
  has_one :abc
end

class Abc
  belongs_to :bar
end
```

And I want to eager load `abc` from `foo`. What would be the best way to do this? Currently this doesn't seem to work:

```
object.foos(include: {bar: :abc})
```

My goal is to avoid making code like this:

```
object.foos.any? do |f|
  f.bar.abc.method_1 && f.bar.abc.method_2 && f.bar.abc.method_3
end
```

And move to more dry code like:

```
object.foos(rails_magic).any? do |x|
  x.method_1 && x.method_2 && x.method_3
end
```

Comment: which rails version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't do nested eager loading on anything other than a class, it makes sense to rearrange your query like so:

```
Foo.includes(:object, :bar => :abc).where('object_id = ?', object.id).references(:object).each do |f|
...
end
```

That query is eager-loading `Object`, as well as loading `ABC` through its own association to `Bar`.